# Array map values and return boolean

Tags: javascript

The code is as follows

```
const {
      aForm,
      bForm,
      eForm,
      qForm,
    } = this.form;

return (
      aForm.isEditing ||
      bForm.isEditing ||
      eForm.isEditing ||
      qForm.isEditing
    );
```

Is there a way to refactor this?
Something like

```
const forms = pick(this.form, [
      "aForm",
      "bForm",
      "eForm",
      "qForm",
    ]);
Object.values(forms).map(f => f.isEditing).join("||") //Need to return boolean value.
```

Comment: Don't know what `pick` is supposed to be, but if `forms` is some sort of dictionary, where the values are objects with an `isEditing` property, `Object.values(forms).every(x => x.isEditing)` should do what you want. [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: pick is used from lodash https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-pick-method/

Comment: Oh, that should of course be `Array.some` not `Array.every` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you already have something close to what we (other viewers) would imagine. Here I'd suggest to use [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to achieve this. It allows you to check if **one** of the items matches the condition (a logical OR `||`).

You have the opposite function which checks [**every**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) value (so a logical AND `&&`).

```ts
const properties = [
  "aForm",
  "bForm",
  "eForm",
  "qForm",
]

return properties.some(prop => {
  const obj = this.form[prop] // Get your form item

  return obj.isEditing;
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const forms = [
  "aForm",
  "bForm",
  "eForm",
  "qForm",
];
const o = Object.values(forms).map(f => eval(f).isEditing).join("||")
eval(o)
```

Comment: Consider not encouraging the use of `eval`. (I am not the asker)

Comment: It's your approach.

Comment: It's true that it's what the OP was trying to do, but the `eval` approach isn't ever a great one. See the other answer.

Comment: In my answers, I'm trying to do minimal changes in the approach of the question owner. Maybe I'm wrong but I think it's more helpful than suggest a solution from scratch.

Comment: In principle it may be ok, to solve an issue based on OP's code. But if the original approachs seems to lead to problematic or even dangerous situtations, is better to clarify that and not suggest things like `eval`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: Evidently, the other answer was more helpful. Why? Because it suggests a simple alternative and explains itself clearly.